How to reload the Create view after AJAX Post?
I have two Model Classes, Telephone and Telephone Model.
To create a new Telephone it is necessary to choose a TelephoneModel.
I want to add within the Telephone Create View, a Modal to create a TelephoneModel without having to leave the view.
Inside the TelephoneController I already added a function that takes the data from the Modal and creates the TelephoneModel in the database. This function is called with an Ajax from the Create View of Telephone.
It correctly adds the TelephoneModel to the BDD, but it doesn't refresh my view.
How do I get the view to reload with the new information to choose from after creating the TelephoneModel in the BDD?
Models:
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Telefono
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public required string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int IpId { get; set; }
        public virtual Ip? Ip { get; set; }
        public int ModeloTelefonoId { get; set; }
        public ModeloTelefono? ModeloTelefono { get; set; }

    }

   public class ModeloTelefono
   {

       public int ID { get; set; }
       public required string Nombre { get; set; }
       public required int MarcaID { get; set; } // Required foreign key property
       public Marca? Marca { get; set; } // Required reference navigation to principal
   }

}


Function:
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddModelo(string Modelo, int MarcaID, string Nombre, int subredID, int ipID)
    {
        var newModelo = new ModeloTelefono
        {
            Nombre = Modelo,
            MarcaID = MarcaID
        };

        if (newModelo != null)
        {
            _context.Add(newModelo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            ViewBag.SubReds = _context.SubRed.ToList();
            ViewData["IpId"] = new SelectList(_context.Ip, "ID", "IpValue", ipID);
            ViewData["SubRedes"] = new SelectList(_context.SubRed, "ID", "Nombre", subredID);
            ViewData["ModeloTelefonoId"] = new SelectList(_context.ModeloTelefono, "ID", "Nombre", newModelo.ID);
            ViewData["Marcas"] = new SelectList(_context.Marca, "ID", "Nombre");


                            
            return View("Create", new Telefono { Nombre = Nombre });
            
        }
        else { return View(); }

    }

Ajax Function:
    function agregarModelo() {

        const Modelo = document.querySelector("#modeloInput").value
        const MarcaID = document.querySelector("#marcaSelect").value;
        const Nombre = document.querySelector("#Nombre").value;
        const subredID = document.querySelector("#Ip_SubRedID").value;
        const ipID = document.querySelector("#ipDropdown").value;


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Telefonoes/AddModelo',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { Modelo: Modelo, MarcaID: MarcaID, Nombre: Nombre, subredID: subredID, ipID: ipID }              
        });

    }


Your Ajax call is a POST with the intention to create a new Model, you are updating the ViewData for populating the view, though that will only be available at render. You don't want the Ajax call to return a View() response as this would normally be used for GET requests, not POST. Instead, consider returning a JSON response object with a success / failure result for creating the Model. For example:
public abstract class InsertResult
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; private set; }
    public string? Message { get; private set; }

    protected InsertResult() { }
}

public class InsertModeloResult : InsertResult
{
    protected InsertModeloResult() : base () { }

    public static InsertModeloResult Success()
    {
        return new InsertModeloResult { IsSucessful = true };
    }

    public static InsertModeloResult Failure(string message)
    {
        return new InsertModeloResult { Message = message };
    }
}

Then in your method you can return Json(InsertModeloResult.Success()) after the Model is successfully inserted, or something like Json(InsertModeloResult.Failure("The telephone model could not be inserted."); or similar if there is an exception or validation failure etc.
The Ajax call is already set up to expect JSON back and inspect the response. If you are already on the Create page one simple option is to just trigger a refresh of the page. The disadvantage of this is that it is another round trip to the server so there is no point refreshing data in your POST call since the reload will be pulling the current data and populating the ViewData anyways. You will typically lose any information the user might have entered prior to opening the dialog to create a new Model.
So a simple refresh would look like:
$.ajax({
    url: '/Telefonoes/AddModelo',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { Modelo: Modelo, MarcaID: MarcaID, Nombre: Nombre, subredID: subredID, ipID: ipID }              
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.IsSuccessful) {
            window.location.reload();   // <- Will reload the current page
        } else {
            toastr.error(result.Message); // Display an error message using Toastr as an example.
        }
    }

A less disruptive/wasteful option would be to have the InsertModelResult include the updated list of telephone models including the ID of one just entered to select by default, then your Ajax call success scenario can find the Model drop-down element and replace the inner elements, selecting the appropriate one, without relying on a full page refresh.
public class InsertModeloResult : InsertResult
{
    public SelectList<ModeloTelefono>? ModeloTelefonos { get; private set; }
    public int? SelectedModeloTelefonoId { get; private set; }

    protected InsertModeloResult() : base () { }

    public static InsertModeloResult Success(int selectedModeloTelefonoId, SelectList<ModeloTelefono> modeloTelefonos)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(modeloTelefonos, nameof(modeloTelefonos));
        return new InsertModelResult
        {
            IsSuccessful = true,
            SelectedModeloTelefonoId = selectedModeloTelefonoId,
            ModeloTelefonos = modeloTelefonos 
        };
    }

    public static InsertModeloResult Failure(string message)
    {
        return new InsertModeloResult(false, message);
    }
}

Re-populating the drop-down using the provided updated items will depend on your rendering, but if you are using Razor components in your views you will need to assign the component with a known Id or use something like @Html.IdFor to get the element if using Form binding. From there you can replace the inner HTML with new elements from the result.ModeloTelefonos. It will involve a bit more work than forcing a page refresh but can be valuable experience for providing a more seamless asynchronous experience for users.
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.IsSuccessful) {
            refreshModeloTelefono(result.ModeloTelefonos, result.SelectedModeloTelefonoId); // <- where this JS method finds the drop down and re-populates and selects the new item...
        } else {
            toastr.error(result.Message); // Display an error message using Toastr as an example.
        }

